# Lookaround assertions in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

im confused what is the use of these lookaround assertions in perl?

example this one:

```
(?=pattern)
```

or the positive lookahead. So here's my questions:

1. How are these useful? what sort of instances they are used?
2. And related to question 1, why would i want to look ahead of the regex pattern? isnt it more work? looking ahead and then executing the pattern matching again.

I need a very clear example if possible. Thanks

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To uppercase what's in between commas, you could use:

```
(my $x = 'a,b,c,d,e') =~ s/(?<=,)([^,]*)(?=,)/ uc($1) /eg;   # a,B,C,D,e

                  a,b,c,d,e
Pass 1 matches      -
Pass 2 matches        -
Pass 3 matches          -
```

If you didn't use lookarounds, this is what you'd get,

```
(my $x = 'a,b,c,d,e') =~ s/,([^,]*),/ ','.uc($1).',' /eg;   # a,B,c,D,e

                  a,b,c,d,e
Pass 1 matches     ---
Pass 2 matches         ---
```

Not only does the lookahead avoid repetition, it doesn't work without it!

---

Another somewhat common use is as part of a string equivalent to `[^CHAR]`.

```
foo(?:(?!foo|bar).)*bar  # foo..bar, with no nested foo or bar
```

---

You can use it to narrow down character classes.

```
\w(?<!\d)     # A word char that's not a digit.
```

Although this can now be done using `(?[ ... ])`.

---

It's also useful in more esoteric patterns.

```
 /a/ && /b/ && /c/
```

can be written as

```
 /^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b).*?c/s
```

Comment: If you don't get this one, you would never have understood my original one. As soon as you figure out why the `c` is not uppercase, everything will be crystal clear from then on.

Comment: ...keep in mind that one pass of /g starts off where the previous pass left off.

Comment: is `a(?=b)` the same as `(?<=a)b`? What im trying to imply on that question is that can I use lookahead instead of lookbehind? its not that i just want to use lookahead all the time. i just want to know if it is possible to use lookahead all the time.

Comment: The first matches `a` if it's followed by `b`. The second matches `b` if it's preceded by `a`, so no, they don't match the same thing at all. Try those patterns in `(my $x = 'ab') =~ s/.../c/; print "$x\n";`

Comment: Note that `(?<=...)` can normally be written as `...\K`, which is way better.

Comment: what is the name of that \K so that i can research about that if it is way better? i mean is it modifiers in regex?

Comment: It's [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) under "Look-Around Assertions". It's basically the same, but more efficient, and isn't limited to patterns that match a constant number of characters like `(?<=...)` is. The downside is that it can only take the place of a `(?<=...)` at the beginning of pattern, but that's about the only place you'll find it.

Comment: is the `.` in your example: `/ ','.uc($1).',' /` a concatination? and I understand now why `c` didnt capitalize, because the first `,` was already found by `/g` right?

Comment: and one more last question for  you, in the answer below, cause acheong87 wont respond to my comment, what is the use of the `.` in the last part? is it a concatination too? i tried coding his example? works if it has `.` and error if none. This example: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$`

Comment: @Belmark Caday, Yes, yes, and answered under his answer. (And he's probably not around at the moment, that's all.)

Comment: hey @ikegami, last question, promise. This nonbacktracking pattern `?>` i dont understand what it means when it supports nonbacktracking

Comment: If you backtrack into `(?>...)`, it will fail to match rather than have `...` try to match something different. e.g. `/^(?>.*)b/` will never match. It's used to tell the engine not to try things you know won't match.

Answer (score 3):

`lookahead` lets you **check** for a pattern without actually **matching** it.

When you do `a(?=b)` ,you would match `a` if its followed by `b`. **Note**:it doesn't match `b`.

---

So,

1>You can extract **hello**(without `#`) from `#hello#` using

```
(?<=#)hello(?=#)
```

2>You can **validate passwords** with requirements such as a password must have 2 digits,2 letters or more with **any other** character

```
^(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[a-z]){2}).*$
```

*Try doing above without lookahead ,you would realize it's importance*

Comment: Re: "Try doing above without lookahead", It's actually clearer if you don't: `/^(?:.*\d/){2}/ && /^(?:.*[a-z]){2}/`.

Comment: Note that `^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2}).*$` can be shortened to `^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?:.*[a-z]){2}`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found lookaheads especially useful for *checking multiple conditions*. For example, consider a regex that checks that a password has at least one lowercase, one uppercase, one numeric, and one symbol character, and is at least 8 characters in length:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$
```

Try to devise a regex to do the same thing *without* lookahead assertions! It's possible, but it's extremely cumbersome.

Meanwhile, I've found lookbehinds especially useful for checking boundary conditions—that is, for example, matching a string of 0's, *unless* it's preceded by another number, like `1000067`.

These are *my* experiences but certainly there are many more practical uses and the way everyone uses a tool can vary from person to person.

Comment: may i ask what is the use of the `.` between the patterns and the quantifier `{8,}`? cause i coded your example and when i missed the `.` i have an error.

Comment: `.` matches any character except newline, so `.{8,}` matches 8 or more character that aren't newlines.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to use lookarounds, e.g.

1. limiting the substring that is considered to be matched: `s/(?<=[0-9])+(?=[0-9])/-/` instead of `s/([0-9])+([0-9])/$1-$2/`.
2. and-ing various conditions together: `/(?=\p{Uppercase}\p{Lowercase})\p{InBasicLatin}{2,}/`.

Answer (score 0):

Lookaround assertions is useful when you need a pattern to help locate the match but you don't want the pattern to be part of what is captured.

Here's a simple scenario with lookahead assertion:

Let's say I have

```
my $text = '98 degrees, 99 Red Balloons, 101 Dalmatians'
```

and I want to change the number of red balloons from its previous value to `9001`, so I use

```
$text =~ s/\d+(?=Red Balloons)/9001/;
```

Comment: @ikegami: true. I need to come up with a better example

Comment: `(?<=...)` in general should be replaced with `...\K`. More efficient and allows for patterns that match a variable number of characters.